# How can i check if a column has missing values in a condition statement IF

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check if a column in my dataframe has a missing value (according to a given condition), if yes i want to replace those missing values with '-'.
Edit: I forgot to mention that my column 'label' is an Integer (0 and 1) and 'attack_cat' is an object (Exploit, Fuzzers,...).
Here's my code:

```
 for i in range(len(sample)):
    if sample['label'] != 0 & sample['attack_cat'].isnull() == True:
        sample['attack_cat'] = sample['attack_cat'].fillna('-')
    else:
        sample['attack_cat']
```

I get this error:
in **nonzero**
raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I checked in debug, it says:

```
    @final
    def __nonzero__(self):
        raise ValueError(
            f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
            "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
        )
```

Do u have any idea how to solve this, thanks.

Comment: `sample['attack_cat'].isnull`: `.isnull` is a method, and should be called: use `sample['attack_cat'].isnull()` instead. The result, however, can't be directly compared to `True`: you'll need something like `.any()` or `.all()`.

Comment: To expand: you're now comparing the value of a method/function to `True`, which will never be true, so the second half of the if statement is always false.

Comment: Also, ` & ` is not the "and" you're looking for: use ` and ` instead.

Comment: `for i in range(len(sample)):` is useless: `i` isn't used, and you're doing the same thing over and over again that loop. I strongly advise you to take some time, read through a few Python tutorials, definitely read through some Pandas guide (the Pandas user's guide is a good start), and look at how things are done there.

Comment: @9769953 Ooh yes, i just forgot to write the (). I tried .isnull().any() and replaced & with and, but still not working. I'm a bit confused

Comment: It would be nice if you can supply a short dataframe with actual relevant example data. It only needs to contain the two relevant column, and possibly 5 to 10 rows. If you do, please provide it as code (`sampel = pd.DataFrame({` etc), not as a table; for copy-paste ease in an answer.

Comment: I edited the post, i added a part of my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, these answers helped in my case ;

> mask = (sample['label'].ne(1)) & (sample['attack_cat'].isnull())
>
> sample.loc[mask, 'attack_cat'] = '-'

and

> sample.loc[(sample['label'] != 1) & (sample['attack_cat'].isna()), 'attack_cat'] = '-'

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [**`pandas.DataFrame.loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a boolean mask :

```
mask = (sample['label'].ne(1)) & (sample['attack_cat'].isnull())

sample.loc[mask, 'attack_cat'] = '-'
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it didn't work, It's like the condition isn't verified because it doesn't replace missing values with '-'. I forgot to mention that my column 'label' is an Integer (0 and 1) and 'attack_cat' is an object (Exploit, Fuzzers,...)

Comment: Try to add the parenthesis. I updated my answer! If the problem persists, you have to give a minimal reproducible example ;)

Comment: Yea I already added parenthesis as well, thank you

Comment: It will be much simpler/faster if you share a reproducible example ;)

Comment: I edited the post, i added a part of my data

Comment: In the sample you shared, there is no rows where the label is not equal to 0 and the attack_cat is NaN. That explains why the replacement doesn't work !

Comment: To make it simpler, based on the sample you shared, what would be like your expected output ?

Comment: I have more than 2,500,000 records, I need to check the whole data.

Comment: I know but can you show your expected output based on the sample you shared ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEJ3C.png

Comment: I've just realized that i did a mistake the condition for label should be label != 1 not 0, that's why it didn't work. Thank Youu

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly I think you should just be able to define your condition and use `.loc` to fill your nulls:

```
cond = (sample['label'] != 0) & (sample['label'].isnull())

sample.loc[cond, 'attack_cat'] = sample.loc[cond, 'attack_cat'].fillna('-')
```

But a few things here. If you have multiple conditions you'll need to put them in parenthesis:

```
(sample['label'] != 0) & (sample['label'].isnull())
```

rather than

```
sample['label'] != 0 & sample['label'].isnull()
```

Also, you don't need `isnull = True` just `isnull()`

Also you're iterating through a range of numbers but not really doing anything with them...`for i in range(len(sample)):` but `i` doesn't show up anywhere else in your code. If you want to iterate through a dataframe and do something row by row you'll need to do something like

```
for index, row in sample.iterrows():
    if row['label'].isnull():
        etc...
```

or

```
for i in range(len(sample)):
    if df.iloc[i]['label'].isnull():
        etc...
```

And lastly, I'm a bit confused on your condition here. You're checking if the values in the column `label` are not equal to 0 but also if they are null. If `sample['label'].isnull()` is part of your condition, you don't need the `sample['label'] != 0` as part of it as well.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it didn't work, It's like the condition isn't verified because it doesn't replace missing values with '-'. I forgot to mention that my column 'label' is an Integer (0 and 1) and 'attack_cat' is an object (Exploit, Fuzzers,...)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate through the dataframe to fill the missing values.
Here's how you could do it:

```py
sample.loc[(sample['label'] != 0) & (sample['attack_cat'].isna()), 'attack_cat'] = '-'
```

### Full code with sample data

```py
# == Necessary Imports =======================================
from __future__ import annotations # Enables type annotations
import pandas as pd
# Used to generate a random sample to test the code.
import numpy as np

# == Generate Random Sample DataFrame ========================

def generate_sample_dataframe(
    size: int = 20,
    choices_attack_cat: list | None = None,
    choices_label: list | None = None,
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Generate a sample dataframe with two columns:

        * 'label'
        * 'attack_cat'

    Parameters
    ----------
    size : int, default=20
        The number of rows in the dataframe.
    choices_attack_cat : list | None, optional
        The possible values for the column 'attack_cat'.
        Default labels:
            * True
            * False
            * None

    choices_label : list | None, optional
        The possible values for the column 'label'.
        Default labels:
            * 0
            * 1
            * 2
            * 3
            * 4
            * 5
            * None

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DataFrame
        A dataframe with two columns: 'label' and 'attack_cat'.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> generate_sample_dataframe(size=5)
       label  attack_cat
    0      0        True
    1      0        True
    2      0        True
    3      0        True
    4      0        True

    >>> generate_sample_dataframe(size=5, choices_attack_cat=[True, False])
       label  attack_cat
    0      0        True
    1      0        True
    2      0        True
    3      0        True
    4      0        True

    >>> generate_sample_dataframe(size=5, choices_label=[0, 1, 2])
       label  attack_cat
    0      0        True
    1      0        True
    2      0        True
    3      0        True
    4      0        True

    >>> generate_sample_dataframe(
    ...     size=5,
    ...     choices_attack_cat=[True, False],
    ...     choices_label=[0, 1, 2],
    ... )
       label  attack_cat
    0      0        True
    1      0        True
    2      0        True
    3      0        True
    4      0        True
    """
    if choices_attack_cat is None:
        choices_attack_cat = [True, False, None]
    elif not hasattr(choices_attack_cat, "__iter__") or isinstance(
        choices_attack_cat, str
    ):
        choices_attack_cat = [choices_attack_cat]
    if choices_label is None:
        choices_label = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, None]
    elif not hasattr(choices_label, "__iter__") or isinstance(
        choices_label, str
    ):
        choices_label = [choices_label]
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "label": np.random.choice(choices_label, size=size),
            "attack_cat": np.random.choice(choices_attack_cat, size=size),
        }
    )


# == Random Sample DataFrame ==================================

sample = generate_sample_dataframe(100)

# == Solution =================================================
# Replace values with "label" different from 0, and
# with missing values for column "attack_cat" with "-"
# Notes:
#  - The `&` operator is the same as `and`. If you want to add an
#    `or` condition, use `|`.
sample.loc[(sample['label'] != 0) & (sample['attack_cat'].isna()), 'attack_cat'] = '-'
```

### Iterating through the dataframe

If you really want to iterate the dataframe, you could use something like this:

```py
for index, row in sample.iterrows():
    if row['label'] != 0 and pd.isna(row['attack_cat']):
        sample.iloc[index]['attack_cat'] = '-'
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it didn't work, It's like the condition isn't verified because it doesn't replace missing values with '-'. I forgot to mention that my column 'label' is an Integer (0 and 1) and 'attack_cat' is an object (Exploit, Fuzzers,...)